# Android 10 custom dialer killed by the system

Tags: android-10, phone-app

I have an oukitel wp5 running android 10. I want to replace the stock call manager (dialer). I have tried several, including the one I have already used on my android 6 phone, but none seems to work.
When started, they work for a while, but after some idle time they seem to be killed by the system. After that no app is there to react to the incoming call. There is only ringing, but no notification about the caller, nothing. Until the app is manually started.
Of course, they are set as default call manager, they get every permission they are asking for. I have checked that they are also excluded from battery optimisation.
Where to check, what to set to kepp it in the background?

Comment: When the app is running, from recents (where you see all running apps), press on the phone app and see if you can "lock" it, so that it's always in memory // Do you have many apps running? If yes, this could be the reason too// If your device is rooted, you can make the phone app a system app// You can try [logging](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logging?tab=Newest) to see if it reveals reason (see the tag wiki, also Play Store has non root logger apps)

Comment: Have you excluded your custom dialer from "battery optimization" (see settings -> battery)? Depending how aggressive the device manufacturer has implemented battery saving killing or stopping an app when in background can be caused by the battery optimizer.

Comment: @Robert, yes, I have checked it was excluded up front.

Comment: @beeshyams How can I "lock" it?

Comment: Could you add a logcat information?

Comment: It depends on your device and Android version .  Google for that. Please add device to your question. On my One Plus 7 , I get an option to lock from 3 dots menu on top right ( Android 10)

Comment: @beeshyams The phone model *is already* in the question: oukitel wp5

Comment: Sorry. missed that. IDK how it can be locked on that